# Same Regex over same content returns 3 different results discriminated by environment

Tags: c#, .net, regex, .net-standard-2.0

Here is the piece of code

```cs
        
var content = @"Script 1 Line 1;
GO
Script 1 Line 2;
GO
";
        
var regex = new Regex("^GO$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
MatchCollection mc = regex.Matches(content);
Debug.WriteLine(mc.Count);
```

When I run this code in "dotnetfiddle.com" in Roslyn or Framework 4.7.2 - same result - `2 matches`.

When I run this code in the Unit Test project, directly in `TestMethod` in Framework 4.7.2 - `0 matches`

When I run this code in the class method in project compiled targeting netstandard2.0, - `1 match`

This is a major headache I need to solve

**Additional Test**

```cs
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine("Script 1 Line 1;");
sb.AppendLine("GO");
sb.AppendLine("Script 1 Line 2;");
sb.AppendLine("GO");
sb.AppendLine();
var content = sb.ToString();
        
Console.WriteLine(content);
// ^^^ changed string creation ^^^
var regex = new Regex("^GO$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
MatchCollection mc = regex.Matches(content);
Console.WriteLine(mc.Count);
```

With this ^^^, even "dotnetfiddle.com" returns `0 matches`

I am still not getting the picture here but obviously something about line breaks in different editors. Then why string builder is doing this?

Comment: I may not have immediate solution for this but just one thing .. can you please try with entire text in single line ? See it still give same result in all env. I suspect something with OS and the way it treat end of line.

Comment: @dotnetstep but how single line will work here if I am looking for `^GO$`, which is `start-GO-end`? Can you give me the pattern to try?

Comment: @dotnetstep tried `var content = "Script 1 Line 1;" + Environment.NewLine + "GO" + Environment.NewLine + "Script 1 Line 2;" + Environment.NewLine + "GO" + Environment.NewLine;`  -- no luck

Comment: Have you tried `"^GO\r?$"`?

Comment: @Zer0 I tried `^GO[\\W]*$` - worked in dotnetfiddle.com, not in VS. Trying now...

Comment: Related [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options#multiline-mode).  In short "$" is looking for `\n`, but depending on environment the new line can be `\r\n` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MSDN(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/anchors-in-regular-expressions?redirectedfrom=MSDN), it states:

> If you use $ with the RegexOptions.Multiline option, the match can also occur at the end of a line. Note that $ matches \n but does not match \r\n (the combination of carriage return and newline characters, or CR/LF). To match the CR/LF character combination, include \r?$ in the regular expression pattern.

When I printed each byte of `content` in visual studio, the result was

`83 99 114 105 112 116 32 49 32 76 105 110 101 32 49 59 13 10 71 79 13 10 83 99 114 105 112 116 32 49 32 76 105 110 101 32 50 59 13 10 71 79 13 10` with carriage return. It does not match GO.

while in dotnetfiddle.com and python, the result was

`83 99 114 105 112 116 32 49 32 76 105 110 101 32 49 59 10 71 79 10 83 99 114 105 112 116 32 49 32 76 105 110 101 32 50 59 10 71 79 10` without carriage return. It matches GO.

When I used StringBuilder in dotnetfiddle, the result was

`83 99 114 105 112 116 32 49 32 76 105 110 101 32 49 59 13 10 71 79 13 10 83 99 114 105 112 116 32 49 32 76 105 110 101 32 50 59 13 10 71 79 13 10 13 10` with carriage return. It does not match GO.

So changing `^GO$` to `^GO\r?$` will make it work.

Comment: That's strange. Can you put ```foreach (var c in content) Console.Write($"{(int)c} ");``` right before running match to print actual data and show what it prints?

Comment: Sorry, I retract my previous statement. It works. Will now test some more

Comment: @T.S. Good that it worked. Actually I learned a new thing from this research too.